# Evaluating a frozen string

Tags: ruby, string, immutability, literals

My vague understanding is that, with Ruby 2.2's `frozen` method on string or Ruby 2.3's `frozen-string-literal: true` pragma, a relevant frozen string literal is evaluated only once throughout program execution **if and only if the string does not have interpolation**. The following seems to illustrate this:

**Not interpolated**

```
#frozen-string-literal: true
5.times{p "".object_id}
```

Outputs (same object IDs):

```
70108065381260
70108065381260
70108065381260
70108065381260
70108065381260
```

**Interpolated**

```
#frozen-string-literal: true
5.times{p "#{}".object_id}
```

Outputs (different object IDs):

```
70108066220720
70108066220600
70108066220420
70108066220300
70108066220180
```

1. What is this property (i.e., being evaluated only once) called? It should be distinct from immutability.
2. Is my understanding of the condition when strings come to have such property correct? Where is the official documentation mentioning this?
3. Is there a way to make an interpolated string be evaluated only once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. [Interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). The strings are said to be **interned**.
2. Not completely. It is more like if the interpreter can decide what the value of the string would be before evaluating it. For example, consider:

   ```
   5.times { puts "#{'foo'}".object_id }
   ```

   The id is the same even though there is interpolation involved.
3. No. This is an internal optimization. The main point of `Object#freeze` is immutability.

---

**UPDATE**: Only literal strings get internalized. This is evident [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/22d8481f080ce4eb758803ad1f60273b6c3a10ad/compile.c#L4796).

I couldn't find the part of the code responsible for interpolation. So I'm  not sure why `"#{'foo'}"` is considered a literal string. Note that wherever this translation occurs, it is on a lower parser level and happens way before any actual processing. This is evident by the fact that `String#freeze` is mapped to [`rb_str_freeze`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/adc0898538b5656a0aae9a4c604876e398db539c/string.c#L2239), which doesn't call [`opt_str_freeze`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d65bc80d3f71bf5423a6a6d9b3f8d4ff2faf6bd5/insns.def#L968).

Comment: Your answer 2. looks correct, and Ruby's behaviour (not your answer) is confusing to me. How could it be the case that "the interpreter can decide" `#{'foo'}` but not `#{}`? The latter is even simpler.

Comment: @sawa, still not sure, will look at the code. My guess would be they simply didn't handle the `"#{}"` case because noone will be using it.

Comment: I like your answer, but I would like to wait a little bit for you or someone else to give a complete answer to 2.

Comment: @sawa, updated my answer, it might not be completely satisfactory. In short - interning works only on literal strings and the interpolation of literal strings inside strings seems to have some optimization hack.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the addition.

Comment: Just "interned," not "internalized."

Comment: @Jordan, I have seen both being used.

Comment: Even if it's not strictly incorrect (which I'm not convinced of), it's still a mistake to lead people to use a term that isn't used in the Ruby docs and will yield fewer search results when they try to find more information on it.

Answer (score -1):

"Frozen" is not about whether the string is evaluated more than once. It is, you are right, about mutability.

A string literal will be *evaluated* every time the line containing it is encountered.

The (only) way to make it be evaluated only once, is to put it in a line of source code that is only executed once, instead of in a loop. A string literal in a loop (or any other part of source code) will always be evaluated every time that line of source code is executed in program flow.

This is indeed a separate thing than whether it is frozen/immutable or not, once evaluated.

The accepted answer is kind of misleading. "It is more like if the interpreter can decide what the value of the string would be before evaluating it."  Nope. Not at all. It needs to be evaluated.  If the string is frozen, then once it IS evaluated, it will use the same location in memory and the same object/object_id (which are two ways of saying the same thing) as all other equivalent strings. But it's still being evaluated, with or without interpolation.

(Without interpolation, 'evaluation' of a string literal is very very quick. With simple interpolation it's usually pretty quick too. You can of course use interpolation to call out to an expensive method though, hypothetically).

Without interpolation, I wouldn't worry about it at all. With interpolation, if you think your interpolation is expensive enough you don't want to do it in a loop -- the only way to avoid it is not to do it in a loop, but create the string once outside the loop.

Ruby docs probably talk about "String literals" rather than "literal Strings". A "String literal" is any String created by bytes in source code (using `''`, `""`, `%Q[]`, or any of the other ways of creating strings literals in source code in ruby).  With or without interpolation.

So what kinds of Strings *aren't* created by String literals? Well, a string created by reading in bytes from a file or network for instance. Or a String created by taking an existing string and calling a method on it that returns a copy, like `some_string.dup`. "String literal" means a string created literally in source code, rather than by reading from external input. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html

Comment: Ofc frozen refers to immutability. The OP was asking about the interning of the strings part of freezing. There is parsing and there is runtime evaluation. [The fork in the logic happens before the runtime evaluation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/22d8481f080ce4eb758803ad1f60273b6c3a10ad/compile.c#L4796), that is what I had in mind. What does the performance of interpolation have to do with the questions? The documentation and the code say literal strings are interned. If your definition of literal string is correct, there is a huge bug with interpolation... Interpolation sort of adds

Comment: *"external input"* as the thing being interpolated can be anything. The important thing here is being static.

Comment: There's no bug with interpolation. Two frozen strings with the same bytes in them will have the same object_id, they'll really be one string.  It doesn't matter if one or both of the strings was created with interpolation. If the bytes are identical, they are the same string. That's what "interning" means. I'm not sure I understand the nature of the confusion here. A string literal is a string created in source code with "quote marks" (or equivalent) whether or not they use interpolation. If a String that was not created with a string literal is interpolated into a string literal.

Comment: It does look like this new feature is going to be awfully confusing, because apparently it's hard to explain what a "string literal" is to people who don't know!

Comment: *"Two frozen strings with the same bytes in them will have the same object_id, they'll really be one string"* -> this is simply not true. Again, this was the major point in the question. Try it yourself -> `"#{}".freeze.object_id == "#{}".freeze.object_id # => false`.

Comment: And I bring up performance because that's the main reason you would care "how many times something is evaluated", so I guessed that was the reason behind that question.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I see, you're right, apparently strings with interpolation aren't interned?

Comment: This is also not true (it was the OP's guess too). Check out: `"#{'foo'}".freeze.object_id == "#{'foo'}".freeze.object_id # => true`. They have interpolation, but are interned. I hope you understand my point now.